# ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 36070300 into shape (704,227,227)

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am getting this error, but do not know why.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\JoshG\PycharmProjects\LeNet\LeNet.py", line 134, in <module>
    train_generator.fit(xtrain.reshape(704, 227, 227))
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 36070300 into shape (704,227,227)
```

Below is the line that is causing the error message.

```
#Import the packages
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

# Image Data Augmentation
train_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=2, horizontal_flip=True, zoom_range=.1)
val_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=2, horizontal_flip=True, zoom_range=.1)
test_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=2, horizontal_flip=True, zoom_range=.1)

# Fitting the augmentation defined above to the data
train_generator.fit(xtrain.reshape(704, 227, 227))
val_generator.fit(x_val.reshape(704, 227, 227))
test_generator.fit(xtest.reshape(704, 227, 227))
```

UPDATE:
I modified the code to the following:

```
# Fitting the augmentation defined above to the data
train_generator.fit(xtrain.reshape(-1, 704, 227, 227))
val_generator.fit(x_val.reshape(-1, 704, 227, 227))
test_generator.fit(xtest.reshape(-1, 704, 227, 227))
```

and now getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\JoshG\PycharmProjects\LeNet\LeNet.py", line 136, in <module>
    val_generator.fit(x_val.reshape(-1, 704, 227, 227))
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 4946784 into shape (704,227,227)
```

So I then removed the `704` and left the `-1` as shown below

```
# Fitting the augmentation defined above to the data
train_generator.fit(xtrain.reshape(-1, 227, 227))
val_generator.fit(x_val.reshape(-1, 227, 227))
test_generator.fit(xtest.reshape(-1, 227, 227))
```

but I then get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\JoshG\PycharmProjects\LeNet\LeNet.py", line 135, in <module>
    train_generator.fit(xtrain.reshape(-1, 227, 227))
  File "C:\Users\JoshG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image\image_data_generator.py", line 935, in fit
    raise ValueError('Input to `.fit()` should have rank 4. '
ValueError: Input to `.fit()` should have rank 4. Got array with shape: (704, 227, 227)
```

Comment: use `print(xtrain.shape)` to see the dimensions of your input. Reshapes can only happen if the product of input and output dimensions is the same

Answer (score 1):

Dividing 36070300 by 227 * 227 gives 700 - not 704.
You can also use `-1` instead of `704` to indicate that the value shall be computed automatically.

Comment: So when I updated it to -1, I get the following error message

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\JoshG\PycharmProjects\LeNet\LeNet.py", line 135, in <module>
    train_generator.fit(xtrain.reshape(-1, 227, 227))
  File "C:\Users\JoshG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image\image_data_generator.py", line 935, in fit
    raise ValueError('Input to `.fit()` should have rank 4. '
ValueError: Input to `.fit()` should have rank 4. Got array with shape: (704, 227, 227)

Comment: Also would it make a difference if the images are gray-scaled?

Comment: It may require an extra dim for channels, assuming grayscaled you could try 'reshape(-1,224,224,1)' or 'reshape(-1, 1, 224, 224)'

Comment: I tried both options provided, but now I am getting the following error message

Comment: ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv2d_3 is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: (None, 227, 227)